# Finish loading cache manifest before showing Web app

Tags: javascript, html, cache-manifest

When you first normally load a Web app with cache manifest, the HTML page shows up, then cache manifest starts downloading the specified files in the background. However, I prefer that cache manifest finishes downloading every listed file before the initial page appears on screen. This is so at the instant the user sees the initial page, he or she can disconnect from the Internet and use all the features of the Web app as intended.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source: https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/w3c_tutorial/storage_tutorial/app_cache_managing.htm

I would look at the App cache events, particularly the `updateready` event.

```
document.body.style.display = 'none'; //this should probably be in your stylesheet.    

applicationCache.addEventListener('cached', function() {
    /* All resources for update are downloaded */
    // show your webpage here
    document.body.style.display = 'block';
});
```

You **might** need to also look at some of the other events that are listed in the linked reference. I don't know if this event will fire if they are no updates.

But there are several events for if there is no manifest file, or if there is no updates available, etc. Seems pretty straight forward though. If you have any quesetions, just comment.

**EDIT**

You will also need to listen for the `noupdate` event to handle the case of the manifest not being updated. (Thank you @Applecot)

```
applicationCache.addEventListener('noupdate', function() {
    //no updates, display the page
    document.body.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just to let you know, I additionally had to use the noupdate event (for loading the page if there's no update available) and the cached event (since Chrome/Safari/Opera had issues with updateready).

Comment: Good to know, I'll add that to my answer for others. Thank you for taking the time to follow-up.